# Django: Logging in manage.py causes misleading exception and traceback

Tags: python, django, logging

In `manage.py` file I want to send an email to admins each time a management command fails.

The following code

`manage.py`

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('management_commands')

try:
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
except Exception as e:
    logger.error('Admin Command Error: %s', ' '.join(sys.argv),
                 exc_info=sys.exc_info())
    raise e
```

is raising

```
"The translation infrastructure cannot be initialized before the "

django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: The translation infrastructure cannot be initialized before the apps registry is ready. Check that you don't make non-lazy gettext calls at import time.`
```

when the actual error in fact was `ImportError: No module named django_inlinecss`.

My settings for the loggers are

```
LOGGING = {
    ...
    'handlers': {
        ...
        'mail_admins': {
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler',
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'include_html': True
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        ...
        'management_commands': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True
        }
    }
}
```

And the first part of the traceback is

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1279, in _log
    self.handle(record)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1289, in handle
    self.callHandlers(record)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1329, in callHandlers
    hdlr.handle(record)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 757, in handle
    self.emit(record)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/log.py", line 128, in emit
    html_message = reporter.get_traceback_html() if self.include_html else None
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/debug.py", line 384, in get_traceback_html
    return t.render(c)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 210, in render
    return self._render(context)
```

This is how I ended up thinking there might be a problem logging related.

Any reason why python logging library would make Django raise `"The translation infrastructure cannot be initialized before the "`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have configured the "mail_admins" logger to include html, which triggers execution of some template rendering in debug views, which itself requires django's translation system to be initialized.

The simplest solution here would be to configure another handler without the "include_html" flag and use this one instead for your logger, ie (warning : totally untested):

```
# logging config

LOGGING = {
    ...
    'handlers': {
        ...
        'mail_admins': {
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler',
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'include_html': True
        },
        'command_mail_admins': {
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler',
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'include_html': False
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        ...
        'management_commands': {
            'handlers': ['command_mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Indeed the problem was because of `include_html: True`. It works correctly without.

Answer (score 0):

This error can also happen with this version of `manage.py` when you've not installed an app that is listed in `INSTALLED_APPS`.

You can remove the except clause in `manage.py` so the exception is displayed without fancy rendering, avoiding the confusing error.